# InstallSheid Disable Reboot in silentmode

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, reboot

I am trying to update a previous version of a product. I have changed the product code but not the upgrade code(Major Upgrade).

During the upgrade process I have to detect if a previous version was installed backup some configuration and restore them after the install .

Every thing seems to work perfectly when running the installer(MSI) by double clicking . But not when i do the upgrade in silent mode .

in silent case the installer detects the previous version backups my configs and then removes the product after this **(It some how restarts the machine)** (< -- this should not happen) after reboot The installer does nothing and there is no product at all in the program files

after adding some custom actions I found out there is a predefined scheduled process "RemoveExistingProducts" after this step executes the reboot happens

I tried every thing like REBOOT=ReallySuppress , / norestart but no luck

I need it work with /q or /qn tags ... It works with /qb but i dont want that

Logs (Silent Mode): https://www.dropbox.com/s/ss41z3pdahxrthv/msilogs.txt?dl=0
(InstallSheild 12 Premier Edition)

Comment: That log is incomplete - it should finish with the result of the upgrade process but just finishes while the older product is being removed. The reboot appears to be coming from the uninstall of that older product because of a ScheduleReboot, and maybe not from the install of the new product. That may have something to do with it, that your /q applies to the new install not the older uninstall in this case.

Comment: I guess the log is supposed to be incomplete cause nothing happens after the reboot

Comment: When we run an update which uninstall step are executed the ones that are of the previous version or the ones that are of new version

Comment: The log entry " Propagated Reboot to the client/parent install." is what indicates that the reboot is coming from the uninstall, not the fresh install. The ScheduleReboot in the uninstall also indicates that issue. It's difficult (maybe impossible) to prevent that uninstall reboot because it's embedded in that uninstall, and not related to your new upgrade.